# CodenameOne: VKB changes the screen

Tags: android, codenameone, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I have a an app developed on CodenameOne platform where I have textfields for manuel input. Each time when the VKB shows on android, the contents of the screen are pushed to bottom and especially the textfield becomes so thin  that no characters can be seen. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

On android when the VKB is launched the Form gets a sizeChanged event, to prevent this behavior you can declare the textfields parent container as a scrollable Y container BoxLayout Y